# Ceiling Hole in Closet, Sprinkler? Light? What is it?

Tags: ceiling

[image]

There is this hole with this gadget in the condo ceiling which is in the bedroom closet. I cannot tell what it is exactly? Does anyone know what this can be? Thanks!

Comment: Can you get a closeup shot of it and post it here?

Comment: I tried zooming in

Comment: It's not a bird. It's not an airplane. It must be . . . . . . .

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a concealed fire sprinkler head that doesn't have the finish trim installed on it.  The sprinkler on the left of the image is complete with the flat trim.

In this type of device, the exposed metal plate is made of a metal that melts at very low temperatures.  The fire melts the metal, and the sprinkler activates.

[image]

Similar: http://www.watts.com/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=7441

You should be very careful with the device.  Do not touch it or poke it.  Since it is in a closet, the installers probably just didn't bother installing the trim, or saved the trim to use later if another more visible unit was damaged.

Comment: Assuming it is a sprinkler the owner should definitely locate the shutoff. It's no fun at all searching for it after an accidental activation.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like a fusible link; part of the fire sprinkler system.

Comment: Hi Paul! How can you tell? How much do you think it would cost to fix?

Comment: I have my doubts about that being a sprinkler -- what would be the deflector looks unlike any sprinkler deflector I've seen.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- What do you think it is?

Comment: @user77231, if you don't know what it is, why would it need to be "fixed"?  What's broken about it?

Comment: I refer you to JPhi1618.  He is clearly on the right track.